# [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.]

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, session, ms-access

The error line:

Source Error:

```
Line 37:         while (rdr.Read()==true)
Line 38:         {
Line 39:             if (TextBoxUserName.Text == (string)rdr["CUserName"]) 
Line 40:             {
Line 41:                 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType,"Error",scriptErrorUserId);
```

It pops up when I tried to register an account.

I use microsoft access as database.

Database - CUserName
Session - sUserName
and there's @eUserName

any idea guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this

```
if (TextBoxUserName.Text == (string)rdr["CUserName"])
```

with

```
if (TextBoxUserName.Text == rdr["CUserName"].ToString())
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if `rdr["CUserName"]` equals to `System.DBNull.Value` first before converting it to `string`. Change this:

```
if (TextBoxUserName.Text == (string)rdr["CUserName"])
```

to this:

```
string userName = rdr["CUserName"] != System.DBNull.Value ? (string)rdr["CUserName"] : string.Empty;
if (TextBoxUserName.Text == userName)
```

Comment: Yours make sense but the other guy answer solved it. I didnt tried yours because I think its not necessary to != system.dbnull.value uh ?

Comment: For string data type, you may not need to check `!= System.DBNull.Value`, but you will need it for other data types, i.e decimal or integer.